# Have property be the same type as property of another class

Tags: c#, class, generics, properties

Can I have property `StudentId` of class `StudentRegistered` be the same type as `Student.Id` (i.e., `byte`) without mentioning `byte` in the `StudentRegistered` declaration?

I would like to define the `Id` type for each derived class of `Person` only once in my application. What am I missing?

```
public class Person<T>
{
    public T Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Student : Person<byte> { }
public class Adult : Person<short> { }

public class StudentRegistered
{
    public /* type */ StudentId { get; set; }
    public int EventId { get; set; }
}
```

---

Edit, to clarify:

- I'm was hoping to avoid having to mention `Student.Id`'s type (i.e., `byte`) anywhere outside the `Student` declaration.
- I don't need `string Name` as a property of `StudentRegistered`.
- There will be no `Adult`s in `StudentRegistered`. A `byte` type for `StudentRegistered.StudentId` is sufficient.

Comment: In your example `StudentRegistered` is not deriving from `Person`.

Comment: Tis is definately a bad idea. What are your trying to achieve with different types for the `ID` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no way to do what you are asking because `StudentRegistered` will be two different types, one with `byte` for `StudentId` and one with `short` for `StudentId`.

There are serious design issues here by requiring different types for a common ID. Your best choise to have common base interface with a `InnerID` method and then link the interfface with the registration.

```
public interface IPerson
{
    ValueType InnerID { get; }
}

public abstract class Person<T> : IPerson
    where T : struct
{
    public T ID { get; set; }
    protected abstract ValueType InnerID { get; }
    ValueType IPerson.InnerID { get { return InnerID; } }
}
public class Student : Person<byte>
{
    protected override ValueType InnerID
    {
        get { return ID; }
    }
}
public class Adult : Person<short>
{
    protected override ValueType InnerID
    {
        get { return ID; }
    }
}

public class StudentRegistered
{
    public ValueType StudentID { get { return Person.InnerID; } }
    public IPerson Person { get; set; }
    public int EventId { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var A=new Student() { ID=100 }; // byte
        var B=new Adult() { ID=1000 };  // short

        var regA=new StudentRegistered() { Person=A };
        Console.WriteLine("Type: {0} Value: {1}", regA.StudentID.GetType().Name, regA.StudentID);
        // Type: Byte Value: 100
        var regB=new StudentRegistered() { Person=B };
        Console.WriteLine("Type: {0} Value: {1}", regB.StudentID.GetType().Name, regB.StudentID);
        // Type: Int16 Value: 1000
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can make it generic and inherit from `Person<T>`

```
public class StudentRegistered<T> : Person<T>
{
   public T StudentId {get; set;};
   public int EventId {get; set;};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use generics somewhere, you could do:

```
public class StudentRegistered<TS, TId> where TS : Person<TId>
{
  public TId StudentId {get; set;}
  public int EventId {get; set;}
}
```